# linking fails while interfacing with Swig

Tags: python, linker, cmake, swig

I am trying to link a program that interfaces C++ and Python through Swig. I'm also using CMake to ease the development on the C++ portion. The Swig part on the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(SWIG REQUIRED)
include(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

message(STATUS "PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH: ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH}")
message(STATUS "PYTHON_LIBRARIES:    ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}")


include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/core)

set(CMAKE_SWIG_OUTDIR ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/../lib/test)

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(swig/core.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
set_source_files_properties(swig/core.i SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall;-c++;-shadow")
swig_add_module(core python swig/core.i core/foo.cpp)
swig_link_libraries(core test_core ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

The linking error is as follows:

```
Scanning dependencies of target _core
[ 66%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_core.dir/__/lib/test/corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
[ 83%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/_core.dir/core/foo.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared module _core.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_PyClass_Type", referenced from:
      SwigPyClientData_New(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInstance_NewRaw", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_NewShadowInstance(SwigPyClientData*, _object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInstance_Type", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_GetSwigThis(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInt_AsLong", referenced from:
      SWIG_AsVal_long(_object*, long*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SWIG_AsVal_unsigned_SS_long(_object*, unsigned long*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SWIG_AsVal_double(_object*, double*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyInt_FromLong", referenced from:
      SWIG_From_int(int) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_AsString", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_str_AsChar(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_AsStringAndSize", referenced from:
      SWIG_AsCharPtrAndSize(_object*, char**, unsigned long*, int*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_ConcatAndDel", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_repr(SwigPyObject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      swig_varlink_str(swig_varlinkobject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_Format", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_format(char const*, SwigPyObject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_FromFormat", referenced from:
      SwigPyObject_repr(SwigPyObject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SwigPyPacked_repr(SwigPyPacked*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SwigPyPacked_str(SwigPyPacked*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_FromString", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_str_FromChar(char const*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      swig_varlink_repr(swig_varlinkobject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      swig_varlink_str(swig_varlinkobject*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_PyString_FromStringAndSize", referenced from:
      SWIG_FromCharPtrAndSize(char const*, unsigned long) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "_Py_InitModule4_64", referenced from:
      _init_core in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
      SWIG_Python_SetModule(swig_module_info*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
  "__PyInstance_Lookup", referenced from:
      SWIG_Python_GetSwigThis(_object*) in corePYTHON_wrap.cxx.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[3]: *** [_core.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/_core.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [core] Error 2
```

I have no idea where to start searching for this bug. Is this a Swig error? or it's not linking correctly to the Python library? I'm using python 3.

**EDIT**

The problem seems to come from a mismatch between the Python libraries found in the system by the CMake `FindPythonLibs.cmake` code. This is the output of the configure part:

```
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/libpython3.4.dylib (found version "2.7.5") 
-- PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers
-- PYTHON_LIBRARIES:    /usr/lib/libpython3.4.dylib
```

where clearly the version found does not correspond to "2.7.5". So if I manually change the variable `PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR` to `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Headers`, which are the headers for the corresponding 3.4 version of Python, the problem vanishes. So then it seems there is a bug in the CMake `FindPythonLibs.cmake` code.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/Headers

Comment: Seems like it cannot link correctly to the Python 3 library.

Comment: It seems like it, but as you see in the CMake part, I'm limiting with the python library. I will try to find out if those symbols are in that library or not.